# Google Maps JS API - Advanced Marker - show only nearest markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geocode

I have the following Google Maps API code which displays AdvancedMarkers markers on the map from a JSON list of postcodes. Then when a postcode is entered (for example "SP4") into the form it puts a custom purple marker onto the map and contimues to display all AdvancedMarkers/postcodes from the JSON list.

How can I display only the nearest 5 AdvancedMarkers/postcodes to the entered location/marker?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geocoding Service</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY-GOES-HERE&region=GB&libraries=geometry,marker&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer async></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style>
      /**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
      /*
       * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
       * that contains the map.
       */
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      /*
       * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window.
       */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      input[type=text] {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin-right: 0;
        min-width: 25%;
      }

      input[type=button] {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
      input[type=button]:hover {
        background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
      }
      input[type=button].button-primary {
        background-color: #1a73e8;
        color: white;
      }
      input[type=button].button-primary:hover {
        background-color: #1765cc;
      }
      input[type=button].button-secondary {
        background-color: white;
        color: #1a73e8;
      }
      input[type=button].button-secondary:hover {
        background-color: #d2e3fc;
      }

      #response-container {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 50%;
        max-width: 90%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
        font-size: small;
      }

      #instructions {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 1rem;
        font-size: medium;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="postcodeInput">Enter Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" id="postcodeInput">
      <button id="submitButton" onclick="findNearestMarkers()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      /**
       * @license
       * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
       * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
       */
              // @ts-nocheck TODO remove when fixed

      let map;
      let marker;
      let markers = [];
      let geocoder;
      let jsonMapData;


      async function initMap() {

        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
        const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

        map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 54.11202, lng: -5.19578},
          mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
          mapTypeControl: false,
        });

        const postcodeInput = document.getElementById('postcodeInput').value;
        const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitButton');

        const jsonMapData = {
          "data": [{"Postcode": "SP11DE", "PinColour": "#008000"}, {"Postcode": "SP12AJ", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12AJ", "PinColour": "#FF0000"}, {"Postcode": "SP12AQ", "PinColour": "#008000"}, {"Postcode": "SP12AQ", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12LP", "PinColour": "#008000"}, {"Postcode": "SP12LP", "PinColour": "#008000"}, {"Postcode": "SP12TJ", "PinColour": "#FF0000"}, {"Postcode": "SP27EJ", "PinColour": "#008000"}, {"Postcode": "SP27EJ", "PinColour": "#FF0000"}, {"Postcode": "SP27EJ", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27NP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27NP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP54JA", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12BP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12BP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12QB", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13ST", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13ST", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13ST", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13TS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13TS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27PY", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27SU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27YS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27YS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27YS"}, {"Postcode": "SP27YS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27YS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP28BJ", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP28RH", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP29LE", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP29LE", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP11DP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP11DP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP11DP", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12DD", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12DD", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP12PU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP13QS", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}, {"Postcode": "SP27NU", "PinColour": "#FFBF00"}]
        };

        // Loop through the postcode data array
        jsonMapData.data.forEach(postcodeData => {
          const postcode = postcodeData.Postcode;
          const pinColour = postcodeData.PinColour;
          console.log(pinColour);

          //Geocode the entered postcode
          const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode({address: postcode + ', UK'}, (results, status) => {
            if (status === 'OK' && results[0]) {
              // create a marker for each postcode
              const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                content: new PinElement({
                  background: pinColour,
                  borderColor: "#FFF",
                  glyphColor: "white"
                }).element,
              });
              markers.push(marker);
              console.log(marker);
            } else {
              console.error('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
          });
        });
        //.catch(error => console.error('Error loading JSON data: ', error));
      }

      function findNearestMarkers() {
        const postcodeInput = document.getElementById('postcodeInput').value;

        // Geocode the entered postcode
        const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ address: postcodeInput + ', UK' }, (results, status) => {
          if (status === 'OK' && results[0]) {
            const enteredLocation = results[0].geometry.location;

            // Create a marker for the entered location
            const enteredLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: enteredLocation,
              map: map,
              title: postcodeInput,
              icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png'
            });

            // Set map center and zoom to enetered location
            map.setCenter(enteredLocation);
            map.setZoom(11);

            // Filter nearest markers
            const nearestMarkers = markers.filter(marker => {
              const markerLocation = marker.position;
              const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(enteredLocation, markerLocation);
              const miles = distance / 1609.34;
              return distance;
            });


            // Display nearest markers on map
            clearMarkers();

            nearestMarkers.forEach(marker => {
              marker.setMap(map);
            })

            // Log nearest markers as JSON in the console
            const nearestMarkersJSON = nearestMarkers.map(marker => ({
              Position: results[0].geometry.location
            }));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(nearestMarkersJSON));
          } else {
            console.error('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

      // Clear all markers from map
      function clearMarkers() {
        markers.forEach(marker => {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```